# Conexión base de datos mysql con Power Apps

Tags: mysql, powerbi, microsoft, mysqldb

Estoy intentando realizar una conexión entre una base de datos MySQL y una aplicación creada en PowerApps. El servidor de la base de datos es AWS. Observé que debía de crear una puerta de enlace desde mi computador para poder acceder a la base de datos, realicé todos esos pasos que decía la documentación pero me aparece este error
[image: Error conexión power apps con mysql]